# Tableau calculated fields from 2 dimensions

Tags: tableau-api, dimensions, calculation

I have a situation in Tableau where I need to do a calculation, but am stuck as to how best to approach it.

I have data in a table like this:

Organisation ID (Measure), Country (Dimension), FY16 Status (Dimension has 3 different values (Low,Medium,High)), FY17 Status (Dimension has 3 different values (Low,Medium,High)).

Sample of the Data:
12345, France, Low, Medium
12346, France, Medium, Medium
12347, France, High, Medium
12348, France, Low, High

What I need to do is create a table that shows the following columns:

- Country (rows)
- Count of Organisations per FY16 Low
- Count of Organisations per FY17 Low
- (Count of Orgs per FY17 Low - Count of Orgs per FY16 Low)/Count of Orgs per FY16 Low.
- Count of Organisations per FY16 Medium
- Count of Organisations per FY17 Medium
- (Count of Orgs per FY17 Medium - Count of Orgs per FY16 Medium)/Count of Orgs per FY16 Medium.
- Count of Organisations per FY16 High
- Count of Organisations per FY17 High
- (Count of Orgs per FY17 High - Count of Orgs per FY16 High)/Count of Orgs per FY16 High.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please find the link to the [Workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wqtk3u6nvvxyjls/Country%20FY16%20vs%20FY17.twbx?dl=0) here with a description of what exactly I am trying to achieve also in the Dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple.

Create `Low in FY16` as calculated field with formula

```
IF [FY16 Status] = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Create `Low/Medium/High in FY16/FY17Y` in the same way

Create `Low Change` as calculated field with formula

```
(SUM([Low in FY17])-SUM([Low in FY16]))/SUM([Low in FY16])
```

Create `Medium Change` and `High Change` as well

Now you got all the columns it's time to create a sheet

[image: Sheet]

If you need I've uploaded this sheet as
[Tableau workbook with Excel data](http://www.expirebox.com/download/7e40b74b8fe0c1e9df8cee36e0994a25.html) (link to be expired in 48 hours)

Comment: Thank you Nick. This was EXACTLY word for word what I was looking for. I knew I had all of the data I just couldn't wrap my head around it. Now that I know how to do this, I can use it elsewhere as well. This will help me greatly. Cheers!